# Injection of autowired dependencies fails on one server but none of others

Tags: java, spring, postgresql, autowired

We have an unusual problem at my work where an application starts up fine on all servers except one. I've had to change some of the class names here and I can't easily post all the startup logs but I'm wondering if there is something that governs the ordering of the component scans on startup.

In terms of server config the machines are built using puppet and the code is deployed automatically. I've even tried rsyncing from one server to another. I've also compared the package listings. I've also run the Postgres database locally. The application is running on ubuntu inside a lxc container inside a custom rolled java and tomcat runtime.

```
ERROR [2014-12-31 16:18:44,754] org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet - [] Context initialization failed
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'onePetroCartController': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: private com.company.internalproductname.p13n.service.spring.UserAuthenticationService com.company.customer.project.web.controllers.OnePetroCartController.userAuthenicationService; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type [com.company.internalproductname.p13n.service.spring.UserAuthenticationService] found for dependency: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}
```

Configuration

```
@Configuration
@ComponentScan(basePackages = {
"com.company.customer.project.web.controllers",
"com.company.customer.project.frontend",
"com.company.customer.project.managers",
"com.company.customer.project.service",
"com.company.customer.project.authorization",
"com.company.customer.project.authentication",
"com.company.internalproductname.frontend.controllers",
"com.company.internalproductname.dao",
"com.company.internalproductname.utils",
"com.company.internalproductname.web.controllers.robots",
"com.company.internalproductname.service",
"com.company.internalproductname.managers",
"com.company.internalproductname.search.metasearch",
"com.company.internalproductname.freemarker"
```

},

Jar files.

```
activation-1.1.jar                             jasypt-1.4.1.jar                                scala-library-2.10.4.jar
annotations-1.0.0.jar                          JavaEWAH-0.7.9.jar                              company-util-querymap-1.5.jar
antlr-2.7.7.jar                                javagit-0.2.1.jar                               sgk-3.4.1.jar
aopalliance-1.0.jar                            javassist-3.17.1-GA.jar                         internalproductname-commons-1.5.4.jar
apache-mime4j-core-0.7.2.jar                   java-xmlbuilder-0.4.jar                         internalproductname-config-1.5.4.jar
apache-mime4j-dom-0.7.2.jar                    jaxb-api-2.1.jar                                internalproductname-counter-release4-1.5.4.jar
asm-3.3.1.jar                                  jaxb-impl-2.1.jar                               internalproductname-ecommerce-1.5.4.jar
asm-commons-3.1.jar                            jboss-logging-3.1.0.GA.jar                      internalproductname-fragr-1.5.4.jar
asm-tree-3.1.jar                               jboss-transaction-api_1.1_spec-1.0.0.Final.jar  internalproductname-frontend-1.5.4.jar
aspectjrt-1.7.3.jar                            jcl-over-slf4j-1.6.4.jar                        internalproductname-loader-1.5.4.jar
aspectjweaver-1.7.3.jar                        jdom-1.0.jar                                    internalproductname-locator-1.5.4.jar
async-http-client-1.7.22.jar                   jedis-2.4.2.jar                                 internalproductname-p13n-1.5.4.jar
aws-utils-1.5.4.jar                            jempbox-1.7.1.jar                               slf4j-api-1.6.4.jar
bcmail-jdk15-1.45.jar                          jersey-client-1.0.jar                           snakeyaml-1.6.jar
bcprov-jdk15-1.45.jar                          jersey-core-1.0.jar                             solr-appender-1.2.0.jar
bcprov-jdk16-1.46.jar                          jersey-server-1.0.jar                           solr-commons-csv-3.5.0.jar
boilerpipe-1.1.0.jar                           jets3t-0.9.0.jar                                solr-solrj-4.3.0.jar
braintree-java-2.34.0.jar                      jettison-1.1.jar                                spring-aop-3.2.4.RELEASE.jar
c3p0-0.9.1.2.jar                               jetty-util-8.1.8.v20121106.jar                  spring-aspects-3.2.4.RELEASE.jar
cglib-2.2.2.jar                                jing-20091111.jar                               spring-batch-core-2.2.2.RELEASE.jar
citeproc-data-0.1.jar                          joda-money-0.9.jar                              springbatch-exist-1.5.4.jar
citeproc-java-1.0.jar                          joda-time-2.3.jar                               spring-batch-infrastructure-2.2.2.RELEASE.jar
commons-beanutils-1.8.3.jar                    jsch-0.1.50.jar                                 springbatch-solr-1.5.4.jar
commons-codec-1.6.jar                          jsoup-1.7.2.jar                                 springbatch-utils-1.5.4.jar
commons-compiler-2.6.1.jar                     jsr305-1.3.9.jar                                spring-beans-3.2.4.RELEASE.jar
commons-compress-1.4.jar                       jsr311-api-1.0.jar                              spring-context-3.2.4.RELEASE.jar
commons-fileupload-1.2.2.jar                   jul-to-slf4j-1.6.4.jar                          spring-context-support-3.2.4.RELEASE.jar
commons-io-2.4.jar                             juniversalchardet-1.0.3.jar                     spring-core-3.2.4.RELEASE.jar
commons-lang-2.6.jar                           lesscss-1.3.3.1.resource.jar                    spring-data-commons-core-1.3.0.RELEASE.jar
commons-lang3-3.1.jar                          liquibase-core-3.0.2.jar                        spring-data-jpa-1.1.0.RELEASE.jar
commons-pool2-2.0.jar                          liquibase-slf4j-logger-1.0.0.jar                spring-expression-3.2.4.RELEASE.jar
core-1.1.79.jar                                loader-1.30.6.jar                               spring-jdbc-3.0.7.RELEASE.jar
db-config-1.5.4.jar                            log4j-over-slf4j-1.6.4.jar                      spring-orm-3.2.4.RELEASE.jar
dom4j-1.6.1.jar                                logback-classic-1.0.3.jar                       spring-oxm-3.2.4.RELEASE.jar
domain-1.1.79.jar                              logback-core-1.0.3.jar                          spring-retry-1.0.2.RELEASE.jar
ehcache-core-2.5.1.jar                         logback-gelf-0.9.6p2.jar                        spring-security-acl-3.1.4.RELEASE.jar
ehcache-spring-annotations-1.2.0.jar           mail-1.4.5.jar                                  spring-security-config-3.1.4.RELEASE.jar
email-utils-1.5.4.jar                          metadata-extractor-2.6.2.jar                    spring-security-core-3.1.4.RELEASE.jar
exist-2.0-preview.jar                          metrics-core-2.2.0.jar                          spring-security-javaconfig-1.0.0.M1.jar
exist-utils-1.5.4.jar                          metrics-core-3.0.1.jar                          spring-security-taglibs-3.1.4.RELEASE.jar
fluent-hc-4.3.2.jar                            metrics-ehcache-2.2.0.jar                       spring-security-web-3.1.4.RELEASE.jar
fontbox-1.7.1.jar                              metrics-graphite-2.2.0.jar                      spring-tx-3.2.4.RELEASE.jar
fragr-api-1.3.1.jar                            metrics-healthchecks-3.0.1.jar                  spring-web-3.2.4.RELEASE.jar
freemarker-2.3.19.jar                          metrics-servlet-2.2.0.jar                       spring-webmvc-3.2.4.RELEASE.jar
freemarker-utils-1.5.4.jar                     metrics-web-2.2.0.jar                           stax2-api-3.1.1.jar
frontend-0.25.jar                              mime-util-2.1.3.jar                             stax-api-1.0.1.jar
gag-1.0.1.jar                                  model-1.30.6.jar                                stax-api-1.0-2.jar
gag-agent-1.0.1.jar                            neo4j-graph-algo-2.1.2.jar                      staxmate-2.2.0.jar
geo-ip-0.4.jar                                 neo4j-kernel-2.1.2.jar                          tagsoup-1.2.1.jar
geronimo-jta_1.1_spec-1.1.1.jar                neo4j-primitive-collections-2.1.2.jar           tika-core-1.3.jar
geronimo-stax-api_1.0_spec-1.0.1.jar           netcdf-4.2-min.jar                              tika-parsers-1.3.jar
google-http-client-1.8.3-beta.jar              netty-3.6.6.Final.jar                           tika-utils-1.5.4.jar
gson-2.1.jar                                   newrelic-api-2.14.1.jar                         urlrewritefilter-3.2.0.jar
guava-15.0.jar                                 noggit-0.5.jar                                  utils-1.1.79.jar
hamcrest-core-1.3.RC2.jar                      openpojo-0.4.4.jar                              validation-api-1.0.0.GA.jar
hamcrest-integration-1.3.jar                   org.eclipse.jgit-3.4.1.201406201815-r.jar       vorbis-java-core-0.1.jar
hamcrest-library-1.3.RC2.jar                   org.eclipse.persistence.antlr-2.5.0.jar         vorbis-java-core-0.1-tests.jar
hibernate-commons-annotations-4.0.1.Final.jar  org.eclipse.persistence.asm-2.5.0.jar           vorbis-java-tika-0.1.jar
hibernate-core-4.2.0.Final.jar                 org.eclipse.persistence.core-2.5.0.jar          woodstox-core-asl-4.1.3.jar
hibernate-entitymanager-4.2.0.Final.jar        org.eclipse.persistence.moxy-2.5.0.jar          ws-commons-util-1.0.2.jar
hibernate-jpa-2.0-api-1.0.1.Final.jar          pdfbox-1.7.1.jar                                xalan-2.7.0.jar
hibernate-validator-4.2.0.Final.jar            persistence-1.1.79.jar                          xercesImpl-2.9.1.jar
HikariCP-java6-2.0.1.jar                       poi-3.9.jar                                     xml-apis-1.0.b2.jar
httpclient-4.3.2.jar                           poi-ooxml-3.8.jar                               xmlbeans-2.3.0.jar
httpcore-4.3.2.jar                             poi-ooxml-schemas-3.8.jar                       xmldb-2.0-preview.jar
httpmime-4.3.2.jar                             poi-scratchpad-3.8.jar                          xml-resolver-1.2.jar
icu4j-3.4.4.jar                                postgresql-9.2-1002.jdbc4.jar                   xmlrpc-client-3.1.3.jar
im4java-1.3.2.jar                              postgresql-9.3-1102-jdbc4.jar                   xmlrpc-common-3.1.3.jar
imgscalr-lib-4.2.jar                           prettytime-1.0.8.Final.jar                      xmlunit-1.3.jar
isoparser-1.0-RC-1.jar                         protobuf-java-2.2.0.jar                         xml-utils-1.5.4.jar
isorelax-20030108.jar                          reflections-0.9.9-RC1.jar                       xmpcore-5.1.2.jar
jackson-annotations-2.1.1.jar                  rhino-1.7R3.jar                                 xom-1.2.5.jar
jackson-core-2.1.1.jar                         ris-utils-0.7.jar                               xstream-1.4.2.jar
jackson-core-asl-1.9.7.jar                     rome-1.0.jar                                    xz-1.0.jar
jackson-databind-2.1.1.jar                     sams-comms-1.11.jar                             zookeeper-3.4.5.jar
jackson-mapper-asl-1.9.7.jar                   sanselan-0.97-incubator.jar
janino-2.6.1.jar                               saxonhe-9.4.0.4J.jar
```

Full stack:-

```
ERROR [2015-01-02 18:13:31,503] org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet - [] Context initialization failed
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'onePetroCartController': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: private com.company.internalproductname.p13n.service.spring.UserAuthenticationService com.company.customer.project.web.controllers.OnePetroCartController.userAuthenicationService; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type [com.company.internalproductname.p13n.service.spring.UserAuthenticationService] found for dependency: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}
  at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:288) ~[spring-beans-3.2.4.RELEASE.jar:3.2.4.RELEASE]
  at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1116) ~[spring-beans-3.2.4.RELEASE.jar:3.2.4.RELEASE]
  at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:519) ~[spring-beans-3.2.4.RELEASE.jar:3.2.4.RELEASE]
  at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:458) ~[spring-beans-3.2.4.RELEASE.jar:3.2.4.RELEASE]
  at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:295) ~[spring-beans-3.2.4.RELEASE.jar:3.2.4.RELEASE]
  at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:223) ~[spring-beans-3.2.4.RELEASE.jar:3.2.4.RELEASE]
  at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:292) ~[spring-beans-3.2.4.RELEASE.jar:3.2.4.RELEASE]
  at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:194) ~[spring-beans-3.2.4.RELEASE.jar:3.2.4.RELEASE]
  at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:628) ~[spring-beans-3.2.4.RELEASE.jar:3.2.4.RELEASE]
  at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:932) ~[spring-context-3.2.4.RELEASE.jar:3.2.4.RELEASE]
  at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:479) ~[spring-context-3.2.4.RELEASE.jar:3.2.4.RELEASE]
  at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:651) ~[spring-webmvc-3.2.4.RELEASE.jar:3.2.4.RELEASE]
  at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.initWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:505) ~[spring-webmvc-3.2.4.RELEASE.jar:3.2.4.RELEASE]
  at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.initServletBean(FrameworkServlet.java:459) ~[spring-webmvc-3.2.4.RELEASE.jar:3.2.4.RELEASE]
  at org.springframework.web.servlet.HttpServletBean.init(HttpServletBean.java:136) [spring-webmvc-3.2.4.RELEASE.jar:3.2.4.RELEASE]
  at javax.servlet.GenericServlet.init(GenericServlet.java:160) [servlet-api.jar:3.0.FR]
  at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.initServlet(StandardWrapper.java:1267) [catalina.jar:7.0.34]
  at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.load(StandardWrapper.java:1084) [catalina.jar:7.0.34]
  at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.loadOnStartup(StandardContext.java:5027) [catalina.jar:7.0.34]
  at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5314) [catalina.jar:7.0.34]
  at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150) [catalina.jar:7.0.34]
  at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:901) [catalina.jar:7.0.34]
  at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:877) [catalina.jar:7.0.34]
  at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:633) [catalina.jar:7.0.34]
  at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDescriptor(HostConfig.java:657) [catalina.jar:7.0.34]
  at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig$DeployDescriptor.run(HostConfig.java:1637) [catalina.jar:7.0.34]
  at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:471) [na:1.7.0_09]
  at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:334) [na:1.7.0_09]
  at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:166) [na:1.7.0_09]
  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1110) [na:1.7.0_09]
  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:603) [na:1.7.0_09]
  at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722) [na:1.7.0_09]
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: private com.company.internalproductname.p13n.service.spring.UserAuthenticationService com.company.customer.project.web.controllers.OnePetroCartController.userAuthenicationService; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type [com.company.internalproductname.p13n.service.spring.UserAuthenticationService] found for dependency: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}
  at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:514) ~[spring-beans-3.2.4.RELEASE.jar:3.2.4.RELEASE]
  at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:87) ~[spring-beans-3.2.4.RELEASE.jar:3.2.4.RELEASE]
  at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:285) ~[spring-beans-3.2.4.RELEASE.jar:3.2.4.RELEASE]
  ... 31 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type [com.company.internalproductname.p13n.service.spring.UserAuthenticationService] found for dependency: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}
  at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.raiseNoSuchBeanDefinitionException(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:988) ~[spring-beans-3.2.4.RELEASE.jar:3.2.4.RELEASE]
  at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:858) ~[spring-beans-3.2.4.RELEASE.jar:3.2.4.RELEASE]
  at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:770) ~[spring-beans-3.2.4.RELEASE.jar:3.2.4.RELEASE]
  at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:486) ~[spring-beans-3.2.4.RELEASE.jar:3.2.4.RELEASE]
  ... 33 common frames omitted
```

Full debug stack leading up to failure:-

https://gist.github.com/gilesw/1d24ba50685bbc2d4401

Okay after all that diagnosis and systems work I dusted off my copy of Intellij and went back to look at the code. I'd assumed that due diligence had been done on that but it appears not:-

```
private UserAuthenticationService userAuthenicationService;
```

typo. What I've yet to find out however is why this only manifested itself on one server because that same code is on the other servers.

Comment: Please post the relevant code.

Comment: Please add the full stack trace and the list of dependencies seems incomplete (no Spring?) and doesn't really add much a maven pom would be more interesting.

Comment: The order of component scanning doesn't matter, they order they are detected and registered in doesn't matter. Judging from the stack trace `com.company.internalproductname.p13n.service.spring` isn't part of your `@ComponentScan`. I would also suggest some grooming of your class path as there are for certain libraries multiple versions on the class path. (Jackson, bcprov, metrics, postgresql to name a few).

Comment: The war file on this machine is identical to the war file on all the other servers, which startup fine, so we are not trying to change anything there. We are trying to determine what it might be about this server that causes the autowiring to fail.

Comment: Sometimes Spring swallows circular bean reference errors and gives you the error you're seeing above, and the behavior for ordering of the circular dependencies is undefined and can vary from machine to machine.  I would suggest adding debug flags to the JVM using `-Xdebug -Xrunjdwp:transport=dt_socket,server=y,suspend=y,address=1044` (this suspends until you connect on port 1044), and use a breakpoint at the lines in the stack trace to see if there is an underlying circular dependency issue

Comment: Hi Alex, I managed to connect the debugger but I'm afraid setting breakpoints is a bit beyond me. I was able to inspect the running tomcat http threads and pause them but not the initialisation stage. The developers at my firm will know what to do. However, I've updated the question with some additional stack messages and it looks like the field is being autowired, but it's being destroyed afterwards. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

As per the error trace,

In OnePetroCartController , you are doing autowire to UserAuthenticationService Service.
But, the problem in in UserAuthenticationService is haveing a bean name. And you are not accessing
UserAuthenticationService using that bean Name.

**Solution**
*Solution 1* : user @Qualifier(beanName), then you can able to access UserAuthenticationService bean with its bean name.
*Solution 2* : Use @Resource to inject the Bean.